# count days - iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm trying to make a counter for days , so the user could know in what day he/she is at .

[image: img]

I have the start and end date , and I have the count between start and end 
what I want is to tell the user at what day he is (day1 , day2 , day3 .... )

```
let unit:NSCalendarUnit = [.Month, .Day]
let components = cal!.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [] )
var daysCount = components.day
print(daysCount)
```

any help ?

Comment: If you want to know only the number of days, don't count `.Month`. Keep it as `[.Day]`. Also, you will want to add `1` to the result probably, if you don't want your first day to be `day0`.

Comment: thank you , but what I want is to tell the user at what day he is, eg.(day1 ... then the next day --- day2 ...etc )

Comment: And what exactly does not work for you?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question then all you need to do is get the current date and compare it to your start date. Then the difference in days between the two dates, plus 1, will give you your day number. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let currentDate = NSDate()

let startDate = currentDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-7 * 24 * 60 * 60) // 7 days ago
let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(10 * 24 * 60 * 60) // 10 days after start date (3 days from now)

if endDate.compare(currentDate) == .OrderedDescending {
    // end date is in the future
    let components = cal.components(.Day, fromDate: startDate, toDate: currentDate, options: [])
    let daysCount = components.day
    print("\(daysCount) days passed.")
} else {
    // end date is now or in the past
    let components = cal.components(.Day, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
    let daysCount = components.day
    print("\(daysCount) days passed. you reached the end date.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func daysFromDate(dateA: NSDate, toDate dateB: NSDate) -> Int {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    calendar.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    return calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: dateA, toDate: dateB, options: .MatchStrictly).day
}
```